# Umbraco 4.7.0 Macro not rendering when inserted via Richtext editor

Tags: user-controls, macros, umbraco

I am using umbraco v4.7.0. I have created a Macro for a Usercontrol.ascx and adding it the usual way, and ticking the option "Use in editor".

It renders fine in the RTE, but then when viewing the page it does not load the macro.

I have googled for a while now and cannot find a solution to this problem, also I have been on the umbraco forum/bug lists to see that there are various posts but I havent found a solution to this yet.

Am I missing something simple here? This worked fine in previous versions.

Comment: You're not trying to display the RTE content in a macro are you?  Is it just added to a template as an item?

Comment: No I am creating my macro, allowing it to be used in the editor, adding in to a page through the RTE, but it is not rendered on the page. In the past this worked fine. Add in the RTE and the macro is rendered on the page.

Comment: Right, but the RTE field must be rendered somewhere.  Is that in a template or a macro?

Comment: Ahh yes, the RTE field (alias bodyText) is in the template and works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got an answer finally........in the template masterpage use:

```
<umbraco:Item field="bodyContent" runat="server"></umbraco:Item>
```

instead of something like

```
@Model.bodyContent
```

So that the macro (the one added via the RTE) itself isn't added by another macro (in this case the one displaying "bodyContent" field).

Comment: Thanks for this. I realised that this is what is happening with my body text.

Answer (score 5):

If, as explained in the initial question, what you see in your HTML is something like

```
<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias="macroNameHere" />
```

...and you don't see anything rendered. Then this is a solution for you:

Inside the XSLT (macro) that processes your document type, you may have something like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$currentPage/bodyText" />
```

Change it to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:Item($currentPage/@id,'bodyText')" />
```

This will render the macro contained in your bodyText.

Please note that umbraco will create a DIV around the macro output. To get rid of that DIV you have either to modify the umbraco source code, or do for example a jQuery search and replace to get rid of it.

Comment: This solution is halfway correct, add the RenderMacroContent method to complete the call. http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/rendermacrocontent

Answer (score 1):

You're usercontrol probably requires
   `<form runat="server">`

Try inserting it in the template instead - that created a server error for me, and I found the problem!

Something like this:

```
<form runat="server">
                      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="mainContent" runat="server" />
</form>
```

Where You put Your usercontrol in the placeholder.

Comment: I already have the <form> tag on my templates. Everything works fine if I have the macro(usercontrol.ascx) in a template, but just not when adding it through the RTE. Pain in the ass as I have had to create separate templates when I want to add a usercontrol to a page.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem - did you manage to find an answer?

Comment: not yet. I had to get the project done quickly, so in the end i had to just create a template for each page. Masterpage with in a masterpage within a masterpage. Sucks :|

Answer (score 0):

To Use Macro in Richtext box

you must check the “Use in editor” checkbox under “macro properties” tab.

[image]

And In XSLT when you are printing macro value used following

```
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:Item(@id,'bodyContent')" />
```

to render macro value.

Instead of

```
<xsl:value-of select="bodyContent" />
```